# Parameters in Angular2 ui-router

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-ui-router

I work with angular2 and ui-router (https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng2.html).
I use the stateService in order to move from a state to another in typescript code.
How can i get passed parameter in the new component?
Here some code of the caller component:

```
private editUser(user: User): void {
    this.uiRouter.stateService.go("home.userEdit", { userToEdit: user }, null);
}
```

And here the code of the called component:

```
constructor(private uiRouter: UIRouter, private usersService: UsersService) {
    if (uiRouter.globals.params != null) {
        //this.user = user;
    }
}
```

The problem is that uiRouter.globals.params has always one single property named "#" with null value. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `globals` object is not updated until *after the transition is complete*.  Inject the current [`Transition` object](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html) instead and ask it for its parameters.

```
constructor(private trans: Transition, private usersService: UsersService) {
    var params = trans.params();

}
```

Note: you can also use `resolve` to fetch your user *before* the component is rendered.

```
var state = {
  name: 'user',
  component: UserComponent,
  resolve: [
    { 
      token: 'user', deps: [Transition, UserService], 
      resolveFn: (trans, svc) => 
        svc.getUser(trans.params().userId)
    }
  ]
}

@Component({
 ...
}) 
class UserComponent {
  @Input('user') user: User;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```